# TRIGGER with conditional IF statement

Tags: mysql

```
Drop TRIGGER if exists triggername;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER triggername
 AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 
 IF (
  Select person from table1 e 
  JOIN table1Type et ON e.table1TypeID = et.table1TypeID
  where et.Description = 'University Degree' and e.Active = 1) 
  
  THEN update table2
  set field = 1 ;
  
   ELSE update table2 set field = 0;

END IF;

END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to use a conditional statement to update another table if that condition is met.
So in other words, if the person in table 1 has a type of university degree and is active then update another field in table 2.

Comment: You cannot use a rowset as a condition of IF().

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
AFTER UPDATE 
ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table2
SET field = EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                    FROM table1 e 
                    JOIN table1Type et USING (table1TypeID)
                    WHERE et.Description = 'University Degree' 
                      AND e.Active = 1);
```

Maybe you must use NOT EXISTS (the logic is unclear).

PS. DELIMITER not needed for this trigger code.